# With jQuery selector, cannot pick up element even though I can see it on screen and selector is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, slideshow

I'm building a slideshow from scratch using javascript/jquery. I'm adding a pagination dynamically below the slideshow as numbers. 
What I want is, whatever slide is active then its respective pagination number should be highlighted by adding a class called `active`, which is cached in a variable called `this.active` or `o.active`. For some reason nothing happens, even though I'm using the correct selectors to locate them.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/A3rQS/

You can look at the statement `o.paginationItem`, in the function called `fadingFX()`. I don't know what's wrong with it that it can't be found.

Please, can someone help...?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens:

- you create a new instance of SlideshowMod
- bunch of variables is assigned to that instance (slides, controls... pagination, paginationItem...)
- at this moment, there is no `.pagination` element on the page, so `pagination` and `paginationItem` are not referencing what you think they are
- you call `start()` method and inside it you call `addPagination()` method
- inside of `addPagination` you are creating the `.pagination` element and adding it into DOM
- only now it is possible to get a reference to that element (because it is in the DOM finally), so this is the moment when you should assign `pagination` and `paginationItem` variables

Comment: Thanks @rdamborsky, that's my problem, I don't know where in the code I should start to assign the `pagination` and `paginationItem`. Please can you tell me where?

Comment: You can to assign those right after you add your .pagination element into DOM or any time after that. It makes sense to set those variables in this.addPagination() method. For example right after $('.slideshow').append(paginWrap). You will also need to add couple of if statements to the rest of your code, or refactor a bit to get o.paginationItem to separate method and do conditions check ups there.

Comment: Many thanks @rdamborsky, it works now... It was all about when a new element is added to the DOM after the DOM itself was full established. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misreading the code, you're only setting the value of `paginationItem` *once*, with this line:

```
this.paginationItem = this.pagination.find('li');
```

That's not dynamic, by which I mean it doesn't update when the result of calling `this.pagination.find('li')` would have changed - it's simply set to whatever the value was *when that line of code was executed*. If you want it to change, you'll have to call that line of code again.

Comment: Exactly. You probably want to assign this.pagination and this.paginationItem in addPagination() method.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was the jquery object nested in o.paginationItem which returned a length of 0. Reversing to the selector itself made it work :

http://jsfiddle.net/A3rQS/4/

```
        console.log(o.paginationItem.find('.active'));
        console.log($('.pagination').find('.active'));
```

You'll see in the console the difference between the 2 jQuery objects. I think the problem comes from the moment the o.paginationItem is created and how jquery updates (or more likely doesn't) it.

I would advise you refresh the collection each time the function is called, also you have an index problem with activeSlide.index() that returns a i-1 value on a wrong range. If you loose track of your indexes, try to write them in a rel html attribute.

Comment: What jQuery indexes are you talking about in that last sentence? Elements inside a jQuery object are also zero-indexed.

Comment: Yes this is myBad, somehow recalled jquery indexes to be based one, thought it was with each() loop but not even. Edited the answer, thanks.